# why is it appending numbers 0 and 1 everytime

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to append a the variable imagename but instead of displaying a file name, it is appending numbers '0' then break then '1'. I want to know why is it appending these numbers and not the file names? The imagename variable loops through the imageNameArray variable which contains a $_SESSION variable which retrieves the name of the files which have been uploaded and that $_SESSION variable is  retrieved from the php script where the files are uploaded.

Below is the javascript code where the appending occurs:

```
  function stopImageUpload(success){

var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
 var result = '';



if (success == 1){
result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
for (imagename in imageNameArray)
            {
$('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[imagename]+ '<br/>');

             }

              }
 else {
 result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
              }

 return true;   
 }
```

Below is the php script where it uploads a file and where the $_SESSION variable retrieve its file name:

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    $result = 0;
    $errors = array ();
    $dirImage = "ImageFiles/";


if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

$fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

$fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


$fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

        if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
            if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                $result = 1;


            }
        }

    }

$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];

    ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you're using a `for in` loop on an array, `imageName` will be equal to the array indeces, not its values. Much like `for (i in window)`,where i will list all methods and properties of the window object.

Since this is an array, I strongly recommend you use a `for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)` type of loop, because it's just safer... in both cases you will need to replace

```
$('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
```

with

```
$('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[imagename]+ '<br/>');
```

**EDIT**

The `for` loop probably din't work for you because I left out a bit, because I thought it to be obvious. Unfortunately, obvious things are easy to overlook... as Greg pointed out to me (thx m8) :

```
$('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');
```

if you use the for(i...) style loop. I'll just add the full loop for clarity:

```
for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)
{
    $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');
}
```

To help you further in finding out what might be causing the problem with only one img name showing up, add this right before the loop begins: `console.log(imageArrayName);` and look at your console. Does the array contain more than 1 element? what does it say? While you're at it, try adding this line, too: `console.log((imageArray instanceof Array ? 'for' : 'for-in'));`. Add this line anywhere in the JavaScript function you posted, but outside the loop to avoid cluttering your console all to much...

Let me know what you find out

Comment: Hi, When you say you strongly recommend using: `for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) `, do I define arr as arr = 'imageNameArray?' is there any other defining I need to do? Sorry it is because I am actually awful when it comes to using loops lol :). That is why I looped it the way I did as it was simpler but I prefer the other way if it is safer

Comment: I have just realised that if I upload a file (dog.png), then it appends the file name dog.png which is fine, but then if I upload file cat.png, it appends the file name dog.png again, why is this?

Comment: just `for(i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)` will do.

Comment: can you post the code you're using? or just do a `console.log(imageNameArray)` to see what's inside the array

Comment: I have updated code above to show the code I am using, I have left the loop to what it originally was because when I tried: `for(i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)`, it gives me an error saying undefined imagename, I will sort the loop out later but I don't know why it is only apending 1 file name for all uploaded files

Comment: I also advise against `for (i=0; ...)` because you are using the global variable `i`. `for (var i=0; ...)` is a better choice. Keeps the scope of `i` local and avoids surprises down the line.

Comment: That, too, is one of those things I regarded as obvious. I used a local in the edit part of my answer, though

Comment: I will mark this as best answer, it isn't quite working 100% but it is nearly there. Anyway I will ask this as a seperate question as you have fixed it so that it does not display 0 and 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `for (var in array)` iterates over the indices of the array. You should be doing

```
$('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[imagename] + '<br/>');
```

Comment: I have just realised that if I upload a file (dog.png), then it appends the file name dog.png which is fine, but then if I upload file cat.png, it appends the file name dog.png again, why is this?